# Laravel eloquent omits null values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm trying to do a left join using two tables, where I need to get all user id and name in first which satisfies a condition and total number of rows in the second table for each user. If a user doesn't have a row in the second table, it must be null or zero.

This is my eloquent query.

```
$users->where('users.access_type', '=', 'type1')->orwhere('users.access_type', '=', 'type2')
                ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM table2 WHERE date > '2014-09-17 16:30:04' GROUP BY user_id) temp_table"), function($leftJoin) {
                    $leftJoin->on('temp_table.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id');
                })->select(DB::raw('users.user_id, users.name, temp_table.count as count'))->orderBy('count')->get();
```

which doesn't returns the user with null count value. instead it returns the user with least count. I printed the query log and copied the raw query for the above query, filled the values and executed. which works perfectly and also returns the user with null entries. No changes made to the query obtained from query log other than adding the values. Copying the raw query below.

```
select users.user_id, users.name, temp_table.count as count from `users` left join (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM table2 WHERE date > '2014-09-17 16:30:04' GROUP BY user_id) temp_table on `temp_table`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` where `users`.`access_type` = 'type1' or `users`.`access_type` = 'type2' order by `count` asc
```

I have tried changing the column name of the user_id field for both using `as user`. Also tries replacing null values with zero using `IFNULL`. But still no go. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your Eloquent query, you need to replace the last function call `...->first()` by `...->get()` in order to retrieve all the results instead of only the first one.

Comment: that doesn't matter. Used `->first()` because I need to return the first array only. Anyways, I have updated the question.

Comment: Using `first()` will only return the first query result, which explains why you only get one user, namely the one with the least count, since you order the results by `count`. Using `get()` will return all the users returned by the query. It also explains why the query works when you copy it from the query log, since the `first` is done by Laravel and is not in the database query itself.

Comment: neither `first()` or `get()` returns the entry with null value. Both returns the least value except null. for which I need some help. not for the difference between them. those are self explanatory. Thanks for your try.